# Can we enable tls 1.0 on MSSQL Server 2019 on database level? if yes then how?

Tags: linux, ssl, windows-server, sql-server-2019

i am running sql server 2019 on Linux box and trying to connect using a Windows server 2016 client, how can we enable TLS 1.0 for SQL Server 2019 on the Database/instance level.

TIA.

Comment: *"how can we enable TLS 1.0 for SQL Server 2019"* I'm pretty sure that 2019 does **not** support TLS1.0. Why do you even *want* to use TLS 1.0, it's not secure.

Answer (score 4):

## TLDR

You don't.

## Long answer

You should be using TLS 1.2. If you follow [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15), you'll be up and running using TLS, but you'll be using TLS 1.2.

SQL Server 2019 does not support SSL/TLS1.0